# C# listbox select item on scrolling to it

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, listbox

I have a listbox with about 5 items :
*blank*
1
2
3
4
5

(only one displayed on the GUI scroll at a time   and user has to scroll to others) and based on the value selected I have to do a search . I am keeping the first item in the Collection property as *blank* since by default the first item in a listbox is Selected. Hence if the user doesn't select anything , it will do a search on *blank* and my regex will return ALL if the search is done on *blank*.

However , if the user selects one of the other entries , say 3 and then scrolls to another item , the new item is not registered unless the user clicks on it in the listbox .

I want the selection to be done on scroll .

1)Is there a better way to design this use case by using a different control ?

2) Can selection on scroll be done through properties as opposed to writing some piece of code on some Event handler like say "scrolled"

Comment: Why not use a Combobox?

Comment: I want to restrict the user to the give number of options and not allow the user to enter any text of his own.

Comment: You can do that with a combobox also: see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks . I found another way of doing this . By making the ComboBox a Drop down List.

Setting the DropDownStyle property to  DropDownList instead of DropDown.